# calculate the vertex normals of a sphere

Tags: opengl

I was wondering how I could takes each sphere's vertex stored in my buffer, and calculate the normal to each of them separately.  Is it possible to do it in OpenGL?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OpenGL is typically used to render meshes, not compute them. And normals are part of a mesh's data. It is usually the responsibility of the builder of the mesh to supply normals.

In the case of a sphere, normals are dead simple to compute perfectly. For a given vector position P on the sphere who's center is C, the normal is `norm(P - C)`, where `norm` normalizes the vector.

Comment: my Center is (0,0,0) which is a zero vector

Comment: @TrtTrt: Then that makes the calculation easier, yes?

Comment: oh ok. I thought that it would cause problems

Comment: @TrtTrt Make sure you completely understand what a normal is and what properties it should have. Then make sure you completely understand Nicol's solution for computing sphere normals and why it works. And then think again if it could cause problems when the center is (0,0,0), be these conceptual or mathematical. (And finally accept and up-vote this perfectly correct answer.)

Comment: @NicolBolas ok that seems reasonable.Nicol, I followed exactly your way, by subtracting first and then normalizing (dividing by magnitude) but I am not getting what I am supposed to. Shouldn't I get a sphere that looks like a hedge hog?

Comment: @TrtTrt: Why would it? Normals don't do anything unless you use them for lighting or something. They're just part of the vertex's data.

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to use them for lighting. that why I want my sphere's normals  to be extended a bit, so I can visualize them, as a result my sphere will look like a hedge hog kinda thing

Comment: @TrtTrt: You cannot draw normals. You can draw triangles; you can draw lines. You can draw lines that happen to point along the direction of normals, but that doesn't happen by itself. You have to actually do it. In either case, this is a completely different question, so you should ask that.

Comment: @TrtTrt So you not only want to draw a lit sphere, but also visualize its normals. Why should OpenGL do that for you automatically? You have to generate a set of vertices from the normals and then just draw a set of lines using these generated vertices. These lines should have `v` as one point and `v+a*n` as other point, with `v` being a sphere vertex, `n` its normal and `a` some constant, depending on how large you want the lines to be.

Comment: @NicolBolas basically I want to work out the surface normal direction and augment my wire-frame sphere drawing the short lines representing the normal direction of each vertex. Ok I got this wrong. so I should take each surface patch as a plane, and then calculate and draw it's 
normal right?

Comment: @TrtTrt: Stack Overflow is not a forum. We don't ask and answer questions in comments. Comment boxes are for comments. Questions are answered by you posting a question with the large "Ask Question" button, then someone posts an answer. That's why comments have a small size limit and limited formatting options.

Comment: @NicolBolas ok sorry about that then